# Android : Activity cycle after Force Close

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my application some times it may take large time to load some values( like retrieving driving directions from google maps).This results in the launch of the "Wait" alert dialog.I wish to know what happens when the Force close button is clicked? I mean What code will be run when the force close is enabled? Do we can manually adjust the time for which the "Wait" alert dialog appears? If not what is the default time by which this dialog appears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it can sometimes be annoying but they made it pretty much purposely (in my opinion) to ensure programmers make sure their app runs smoothly with no UI freezing  ..
I cant find the documents about it right now but if I remember correctly its about 4 seconds..
you just need to make sure that there is no UI freeze or delay in your app which means that if your values takes more then a couple of seconds to load they should be loading asynchronously.
you need to move any heavy loading from your main activity to run asynchronusly (using [async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a [thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html)).

Comment: it mainly happens when i try to get driving directions from google map!!

Comment: yes.. any online data pulling should be happening asynchronously. since you don't know how strong the user connection is or how long will it take to pull the data from the servers then you cant make your user wait (freeze the UI) in waiting for the data .. it has to be done in a thread or async-task so the main activity is not waiting for the data. your app wont crash even if it takes it an hour to load as long as your main activity is not freezing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that on force close it just shut down your app's VM .. so no. but don't take my word for it, you can easily check it for yourself by putting a line of code under onDestroy() and see if it runs..

Comment: can you please suggest me a good example or tutorial that dealt with async tasks android?

Comment: I don't know any specific tutorial but in my opinion the best way to get the basic understanding is by reading the official article document-http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html (and also the links I added in my answer) and after that I bet your google skills are as good as mine :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5499/discussion-between-freshdroid-and-joe)

Answer (score 1):

You should read [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) on Android threading.

You never want to perform any long-running tasks on your main thread. If the operation is going to take more than a fraction of a second, you should be using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or creating your own background thread to perform the task.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when you get to that dialog, the Android OS has taken over and is killing your process. If this is a regular occurrence, a stack dump should be of use to figure out what is crashing your app.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing time-consuming initialization on the event thread. You should start a background thread (or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)) to do the initialization work. See the guide topic [Designing for Responsiveness](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html). Follow-up reading should include [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html) and [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).

Comment: @freshDroid - I don't think so. The OS has taken over and is in the process of killing your app.

Comment: @freshDroid - That's the only way, I think. Do all time-consuming work off the event thread. (In Honeycomb and later, I believe, you will get an exception if you try to make a network connection on the event thread.)